# Filter String data in Spark dataframe where data has null values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a way to use filter on a filed in DataFrame which has null data.
Below is my sample DataFrame with two fields: id and value.
value field has a null value in it.

```scala
val testData = Array((1,"actualstring1"),(2,null),(3,"actualstring2"),(4,"testString1"))
val testDataDF = sc.parallelize(testData).toDF("id", "value")
```

I used the below code snippet to filter out the test strings assuming the output to have three records. To my surprise I've got only below two records:

```
testDataDF.filter(!col("value").contains("test")).show
```

which gives the below result:

```
+---+-------------+
| id|        value|
+---+-------------+
|  1|actualstring1|
|  3|actualstring2|
+---+-------------+
```

here we see that the record with `id=2` is ignored in this filteration process.
Im now stuck how to include the row for `id=2` aswell in the output along with the two rows we are getting.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace current condition with a one which defaults to `FALSE`:

```
not(coalesce(col("value").contains("test"), lit(false))
```

where

```
lit(false)
```

is a boolean literal, and

```
coalesce(_, _)
```

returns the first `NOT NULL` element, counting from the left, or `NULL` if such element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can test `col("value") != null` in the filter:

```
testDataDF.filter(col("value") != null && !col("value").contains("test")).show
```